# How can I customize controller output based on developer supplied parameters with Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Is there any way to customize what a controller returns based on a parameter (not a query parameter) provided in a route?  For example, if there are two modes of display, but it depends on the URL accessed as far as which way it's displayed.

A simplified, made up example:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    // $display_mode can be "large" or "small"

    public function show($display_mode = null)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Route:

For /page1 I want $display_mode to be "large", for /page2, I want it to be "small."  How do I pass that in via the function parameter?  This would be the preferred way, but if Laravel does this a different way, let me know.

```
Route::get('/page1', [MyController::class, 'show']);

Route::get('/page2', [MyController::class, 'show']);
```

To get a better idea of what I want to accomplish.  Say the controller function has five different customizable parameters based on both display and business logic.  I can't know in advance what options will apply to the pages that the developer creating routes will want to display.  I just want to make those options available.

Also, the developer making the routes does not want to make URLs with ugly paths such as mypage/large/tiled/system-only.  The end user doesn't need to know about all of the options passed in as parameters to a function.

Rather, the routes should only be /a, /b, and /c and each of those routes underneath the hood represents zero to five customizable options by passing in the options as parameters to the controller function.

edit:

I tried the defaults() method and it works well.  Note that in order for it to work, a separate default() call has to be made for each function parameter.  For example:

```
Route::get('/login/main', [WAYFController::class, 'wayf'] )
    ->defaults('tiledUI', false)
    ->defaults('showAffiliateLogin', true)
    ->defaults('type', 'full');
```

Comment: Check the URL in your `show()` method; if it's `page1`, set `$display_mode` to `'large'`, if it's `page2`, set to `small`.

Comment: If you want `$display_mode` (that should be `$displayMode`, variables are generally `camelCase`) to be available in `show(...)`, then you'd need to use a URL Parameter: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#dependency-injection-route-parameters, so `/page1/{displayMode}`, then `show($displayMode)` would be available, but that still doesn't handle `large` for `page1` and `small` for `page2`; you'd have to do that manually somehow.

Comment: @TimLewis so to summarize, you are saying that what I want to do can't be done.  The idea is a generic parameterized controller with many parameters that can be used on as many pages as the developer sees fit without having to create URL paths that unnecessarily tie all the parameters to the parameters of the function.  I want to do this without unnecessary coupling, which is, in part, the purpose of having function parameters.

Comment: I'm saying it can be done, just not automatically (at least not to my knowledge). You say *"For /page1 I want $display_mode to be "large", for /page2, I want it to be "small.""* , but the follow-up to that is "How"? How do you expect your app to know to use `large` for `page1`? If there's a pattern, like even pages use large, odd uses small, etc, then you can set that up, but this sounds like a manual thing.

Comment: @TimLewis That is a very simplified example.  The real example is in part about display, in part about business logic.  There are several customizations that can be made.  I expected that Laravel would have a capability to pass parameters to a controller function and not have these customizable function parameters coupled to specific things in URL paths.  I see that I was incorrect in that expectation.

Comment: Gotcha. Laravel definitely _can_ facilitate "injecting" things to Controllers, i.e. every Controller method can have `public function whatever(Request $request)`, which makes the `request()` available as a variable `$request`, but everything inside that `$request` var is coming from HTTP headers, form inputs, query strings, URL parameters, etc. So even as a broad concept, these additional configurations _are_ passed in to the Controller _somehow_ via the Request. Does that make sense? You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74619087/edit) if you want to clarify anything 

Comment: @TimLewis  yes.  I am aware of passing in options via query string and parts of URL paths. such as {option1}/{option2}/ etc. That's not what the question is referring to.  The question is about a user requesting /a /b or /c and each of those representing a large number of customizable options in combinations that cannot be pre-known by the original author of the controller.  I would rather not change the question solely due to the answer to a different question being more obvious.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by *"solely due to the answer to a different question being more obvious"*; I wasn't suggesting changing the question, just editing it to provide more details, or specifically, an example of what customizations you'd _expect_ for `/a` vs `/b`, etc. But I don't think that's necessary anymore. I still don't think there's a way to do this "automagically", and you also say *"cannot be pre-known by the original author of the controller"*, so I honestly don't know what you're expecting... Maybe someone else will be able to help, but yeah, I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: @TimLewis ok thanks, I misunderstood.  I did add an /a vs. /b part.  Ok, if it can't be done, that's fine.  Just wanted to make sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, you can do this. You can use the `defaults` method of the `Route` to pass a default value for a parameter:

```
Route::get('testit', function ($display_mode) {
    dump($display_mode);
})->defaults('display_mode', 'large');
```

You can use this to pass arbitrary data to the 'action'.

Another use-case for this is if you had something like a PageController to display a single page but don't want the routes to be dynamic and instead explicitly define the routes you will have:

```
Route::get('about-us', [PageController::class, 'show'])
    ->defaults('page', 'about-us');

Route::get('history', [PageController::class, 'show'])
    ->defaults('page', 'our-history');
```

The `Route` class is Macroable so you could even create a macro to define these defaults on the route:

```
Route::get('about-us', [PageController::class, 'show'])
    ->page('about-us');
```

The `Router` itself is also Macroable so you could define a macro to define all of this into a single method call:

```
Route::page('about-us', 'about-us');
```