# Laravel 8: Storing custom route attributes

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

What is the most simple way to store custom attributes such as page titles or other key value pairs that may be attached to a route?

For example, say I want to add my own metadata data to:

```
Route::get('/themetest', [MyController::class, 'list'])->name('themetest');
```

I thought I could add a route macro to save metadata to be retrieved later using an addMetadata method like

```
Route::get('/themetest', [MyController::class, 'list'])->name('themetest')->addMetadata('title' => 'Page Title');
```

Is that possible?  Doesn't seem like it is.

Is there a standard way to store this type of info? Or, any practical way?  I thought maybe I could store them using default(), but that could change the default parameters for a controller function.

Comment: you can use `defaults` method to set default values for parameters, then you can get those route parameters from the request ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74619087/how-can-i-customize-controller-output-based-on-developer-supplied-parameters-wit/74622892#74622892

Comment: @lagbox I wish I could, but the problem is, those parameters will used for actual default parameters in a controller function, no matter what the name of the default parameter is.   For example, I could have a parameter named '[page_title]' and it will be passed to a parameter in a controller called ($type = null)

Comment: what does your `list` method's signature currently look like, as you don't have to take those parameters

Comment: @lagbox  I'm trying to come up with a generic solution for any function.  Unfortunately, if a controller method has a parameter with a default value, Laravel will give it the value specified in default() no matter what the name of the parameter is.  It will just start putting parameters where they don't belong.  I don't know if that's a bug or a feature.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the 'action' array of the Route to store this information if you had to:

```
// In a Service Provider @ boot

Illuminate\Routing\Route::macro('addMetaData', function ($key, $value) {
    $this->action['meta'][$key] = $value;

    return $this;
});

Illuminate\Routing\Route::macro('getMetaData', function ($key = null) {
    return is_null($key)
        ? $this->getAction('meta')
        : $this->getAction('meta.'. $key);
});

// Route definition

Route::get('/themetest', [MyController::class, 'list'])
    ->name('themetest')
    ->addMetaData('title', 'Page Title');

// Controller method (Route action)

public function list(Request $request)
{
    dump($request->route()->getMetaData('title'));
}
```

Comment: I'm currently looking into middleware with settings like "theme:title=Page Name' but thanks, I'll look into actions as well

Comment: This works nicely. My VS Code doesn't seem to be able to type hint in the provider for some reason, and gives "Undefined property '$action'".

Comment: This does not work or something is missing. He is using `macro` over `lluminate\Routing\Route` meanwhile in the routes we use the `route facade` which uses `routeRegistrar` for the allowed attributes which in the `routeRegistrar' are just hardcoded. Here the link: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteRegistrar.php