# Use Macroable or allowing somehow to add custom attributes to RouteRegistrar

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm doing this:

```
    \Illuminate\Routing\Route::macro('description', function (string $description): AppServiceProvider|\Illuminate\Routing\Route {
        $this->action['description'] = isset($this->action['description']) ? $this->action['description'].$description : $description;
        return $this;
    });
```

So I can do this:

```
Route::post('/test', [TestController::class, 'test'])->description('this is a test description');
```

Then I will access the description as normally should by:

```
$request->route()->getAction('description');
```

The problem I'm facing is that if we add a new mixin/macro on `Illuminate\Routing\Route`, it cannot be accessed from `RouteRegistrar` because the `$allowedAttributes` are hardcoded.

Any work around for this?

Comment: what is the problem? you are trying to call what method on what object?

Comment: @lagbox I have explained the problem in one of your answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74868902/laravel-8-storing-custom-route-attributes/74916531#comment135587494_74916531